# Fatal assert failed - error

Tags: dota-2

It has happened a few times so I thought I should ask what this is and how to fix it..

[image]

Often happens when I try to Watch Game of a friend.. I click Watch Game, it goes to the Loading.. screen with Dota 2 logo, and then it crashes with ^that message.

Any idea what it is?

Comment: Check gamecache integrity with steam

Comment: how to do what wizliz said: rightclick on dota2 in steam->preferences-> local files -> verify integrity of game cache. this will rebuild all damaged data

Comment: Now it says "Sync conflict"...

Comment: @evil you should go to settings of steam -> cloud -> disable steam cloud sync. restart steam, start dota2. restart again, activate sync again. the problem is that you have a different config locally compared to the cloud. you will be asked to take the config from cloud or locally. you should take it from the cloud then